# Windows Folder Shortcut of an Electron App - get the path of that folder?

Tags: node.js, windows, path, electron, registry

## TL;DR

**I want to open my Electron App through a Windows Folder Shortcut (right-click on any folder and click `Run In My Electron App`),  and get the folder path that initiated the app.**

I managed to create the shortcut using windows Registry, but I can't find a way to get the path of **the folder that initiated** the app. (in the shortcut, "Temporary")

[image: Run in my electron app]
[image]

So in the above shortcut, the goal is to know the path of `F:\ePC\Libraries\Videos\Loom\Temporary` inside the electron app. (and the path should always be matching the folder that initiated the app).

A real-world working example: Just like when using WinRAR, you can right-click on a folder and click "Add to archive..." - the WinRAR app knows the path of the folder that has been right-clicked on. (Kind of like "open file with", but "open folder with").

**Another real-world example that works with Electron is Visual Studio Code, you can right-click on a folder and click "Open With Code".** How did they do that?

## My Attempt

I tried to look over the documentation of Electron but only found a way to get the path of the EXE file, but not the folder that excecated that file using the Windows folder shortcut.

I tried also `process.argv` but it gives me the path of the exe file, and not the initiating folder.

#### Steps to reproduce the my attempt and test it yourself:

1. [Get the repository](https://github.com/elron/windows-folder-electron-shortcut) and clone it. (It only has 3 files: [**index.js**](https://github.com/elron/windows-folder-electron-shortcut/blob/main/index.js), [**index.html**](https://github.com/elron/windows-folder-electron-shortcut/blob/main/index.html) and [**package.json**](https://github.com/elron/windows-folder-electron-shortcut/blob/main/package.json)).
2. Open that folder in the command line and run `npm install`
3. Export the electron app by running `npm run package-win`. this should export the exe file to `[relative app path]/rlease-builds/windows-folder-electron-shortcut-win32-ia32/windows-folder-electron-shortcut.exe`.
4. To add the windows shortcut for the app: In the windows, registry create this:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Run In My Electron App\command`

Here's a step by step:

- 4 a. Open "Registry Editor" in Windows.
- 4 b. Head over to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell` and create a new folder called "Run In My Electron App"
- 4 c. Inside the created folder, create `command` folder.
- 4 d. Double click on the default value and change it to the full path of the exe file.

(In my case the default value is: `C:\Users\elron\apps\windows-folder-electron-shortcut\rlease-builds\Paste Folder Icon-win32-ia32\Paste Folder Icon.exe`. **Make sure that the path is YOUR path of .exe file of the exported app.**)

When done with step 4, It should look something like this:

[image]

#### Result:

When running the app through a folder shortcut, it will give you the path of the EXE as expected, but not the path that initiated the app as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Run in my electron app]

And now you can test it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your question is well written, well done :) It might be worth checking what's inside `process.env` but other than that I have no other suggestions sadly.

Comment: @Joshua I appreciate the attempt to help, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the registry add this to your command value:

```
"C:\Users\elron\apps\windows-folder-electron-shortcut\rlease-builds\Paste Folder Icon-win32-ia32\Paste Folder Icon.exe"  "%1"
```

The `"%1"` will pass the initiating directory to your electron application.

You can extract the directory path in your electron application like this:

```js
const exePath = process.argv[0];
const folderPath = process.argv[1];
```